# ADF table - count rows with specific values

Tags: oracle-adf

I have ADF table and I want to count number of rows with specific column value.
For example:

```
ID   Sex
1    Male
2    Female
3    Male
4    Male
```

I want to display at the end of the table
Total number

```
<af:outputText value="Total number of rows #{bindings.VO.estimatedRowCount}" 
           id="ot16" partialTriggers="cb1 cb2"/>
```

How many of them are 'Male'?

```
Total number or rows 4
Males are 3
```

Comment: I can count it from sql statement but I'm asking if there is easy way to get it in ViewController

Comment: using sql statement  is a good solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to get the Iterator of view object and iterate through it to count the desired value.

```
DCIteratorBinding xxIterator = ADFUtils.findIterator("XXViewIterator");
            if (xxIterator.getViewObject().hasNext()) {
                Row row = xxIterator.getViewObject().next();
                if (row != null) {
                    String xx = row.getAttribute("value").toString();
              }
            }
```